# Add a value to an Object in an array if condition is met in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array  `<EmailUser>[]`

```
class EmailUser{
final String id;
final String type;
}
```

I want to iterate over the array and when the condition of `(emailUser.id == id)` is met I want to give this object a value for the type property.

I've seen `firstWhereOrNull` from the collections package. But that returns the object.
Which would involve removing the object and adding it to the array again..
What his the neatest way to do this..

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot assign a new value for `type` field because it's declared as `final`.

Do this instead:

```
class EmailUser {
  int id;
  String type;
  
  EmailUser({
    this.id = 0,
    this.type = '',
  });
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
List<EmailUser> list = ...;
...
for (final user in list) {
  if (user.id == id) {
    user.type = value;
  }
}
```

**Update**

You can also do this:

```
void update(EmailUser user) {
  if (user.id == someId) {
    user.type = 'New Value';
  }
}

...

list.forEach(update);
```